# How to change kendo ui click delay

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

i'm using kendo ui web and have been trying to find the click delay for mobile devices(searched almost all js files). the click happens 500ms after touch end. How do i fix it?

Comment: Which widget/element you're using?

Comment: no widgets... click on any element is laggy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a Kendo UI specific delay - you're probably talking about the 300ms delay mobile browsers use to detect a double tap. You can use [FastClick](http://ftlabs.github.io/fastclick/) to deal with that.

Comment: fastclick looks promising ... will it collapse any of the kendo or jquery functionality? I'm going to try it anyway...

Comment: Works fine so far ... fingers crossed... Thanks mate... :)